# I tried to uncheck compile on save but "import java.util.Scanner" is still not working

Tags: java, netbeans, java.util.scanner

I'm new to coding so I'm really sorry if you guys find this question foolish.

so this is my code so far, also I'm using netbeans.

```
package act.pkg3.program.pkg1;

public class Act3Program1 {
    
import java.util.Scanner;
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int intComputer;
    
    System.out.println("please enter the number of computer/monitor you own:");
    intComputer = keyedInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The total number of tons of water used to manufacture:");
    intComputer = intComputer * 1,5 ;
    }
    
}
```

I tried to search for the answer and I heard people said to uncheck the "compile on save". I did turn it off but the code still couldn't run properly, and I'm also not sure if something could be wrong with my code.

the output look like this:

```
ant -f "C:\\Users\\Vee\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Act 3 program 1" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Vee\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Act 3 program 1\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Vee\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Act 3 program 1\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Vee\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Act 3 program 1\build\classes
C:\Users\Vee\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Act 3 program 1\src\act\pkg3\program\pkg1\Act3Program1.java:9: error: illegal start of type
import java.util.Scanner;
C:\Users\Vee\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Act 3 program 1\src\act\pkg3\program\pkg1\Act3Program1.java:9: error: <identifier> expected
import java.util.Scanner;
C:\Users\Vee\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Act 3 program 1\src\act\pkg3\program\pkg1\Act3Program1.java:17: error: ';' expected
    intComputer = intComputer * 1,5 ;
3 errors
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 1):

This class definition is invalid:

```
public class Act3Program1 {
    import java.util.Scanner;
}
```

While this one is valid:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Act3Program1 {
}
```

The only difference is where the "import" statement went. Import statements go at the top, *outside* of a class definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:) happy coding.

```
package act.pkg3.program.pkg1;

public class Act3Program1 {
    
import java.util.Scanner;
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int intComputer;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter the number of computer/monitor you own:");
    intComputer = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The total number of tons of water used to manufacture:");
    intComputer = intComputer * 1,5 ;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: omg thank you so much, and have fun coding too xD

Comment: This code does not compile.